# Traceroute : Ip check

Tags: linux, traceroute

Using traceroute i was trying to see which routers the packet was travelling through

```
traceroute google.co.in
```

This seems to show that packets go from my isp to google's servers which are in US but google india servers are in hyderabad/bangalore . Why is this anamaoly ?

Comment: Because Google's main server farm does the routing (I would guess). Thus, it has to find out where you are from, and Google's US servers are the ones that do that.

Answer (score 2):

Check what IP address are associated with "google.co.in"

In the USA, I get this:

```
11 % host google.co.in
google.co.in has address 74.125.225.52
google.co.in has address 74.125.225.48
google.co.in has address 74.125.225.49
google.co.in has address 74.125.225.50
google.co.in has address 74.125.225.51
...
```

If you know DNS names of the google india servers in hyderabad/bangalore see if they  match any IP address from `host` or `dnsquery` or `nslookup`. That is, it may just be a DNS server difference.

Answer (score 0):

Google reroutes traffic because of various reasons. They might have maintenance in data center you are assuming to use. Or power is cheaper at the moment cheaper somewhere else. It's impossible to know where, or why, service is coming from some location.

Answer (score 0):

Google knows your IP (and thus rough location) from your DNS lookup and routes your request accordingly.  While Google has offices in India, they may not have datacenters there.